# Why does onresize fire when it shouldn't at low zoom levels in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, zooming, onresize

I wrote some jquery to resize elements and close all open popups on my page when the browser window is resized:

```
    addEvent({
        target: window,
        eventListener: 'onresize',
        func: function (e) {
            resizeElements(); //This resizes loads of stuff
            closeAllPopups(); //Closes any open popups
        }
    });
```

This works fine at 100% zoom. However, at zoom levels less than 90% onresize keeps getting called, even when the window has not been resized. The effect is that popups won't open- they immediately close.

This only seems to happen on IE8. It works fine for Chrome.

Any ideas why this is happening- Is it simply an IE8 bug? Can anyone suggest a fix or a workaround?

Comment: When resizeElements() is called, isn't it retrigger window resize event? (if elements have static or relative position) Why only on IE8? i don't know.

Comment: No it doesn't retrigger it, maybe because resizeElements doesn't resize every element, just some of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about checking the window original size and re-size size, then try to call your function?

So, even if you are in 90% view on load, this window size will be original size and only when you resize (under 90% view), your functions will be called?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var original_width = $(window).width();
    var original_height = $(window).height();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var resize_width = $(window).width();
        var resize_height = $(window).height();

        if(original_width != resize_width && original_height != resize_height){
            alert('You resized!');
            // resizeElements(); //This resizes loads of stuff
            // closeAllPopups(); //Closes any open popups
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Laughably simple. But perfect! Thank you- this works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try maybe to debounce it using a timer:

```
addEvent({
        target: window,
        eventListener: 'onresize',
        func: function (e) {
            clearTimeout(window.resizeTimeout);
            window.resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                resizeElements(); //This resizes loads of stuff
                closeAllPopups(); //Closes any open popups
            },50);
        }
    });
```

I'm using here global object window to set resizeTimeout variable but better would be to use a local variable.

Comment: Sorry. Debouncing is no use here. The problem is that `onresize` gets called _at all_. It gets called even when the window is not resized. (I'll clarify my wording in the question)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "fix" this bug in the browser itself, so you are just going to have to work-around having a resize event that constantly triggers. So roasted was right about using the time, but you are not looking for a timer. You need to store the time and then ensure that enough time has elapsed before the event is triggered again, like so:

```
var _interval = 1000;// milliseconds
var _resize = 0;
addEvent({
    target: window,
    eventListener: 'onresize',
    func: function (e) {
        if (Date.now() - _resize < _interval)
            return;
        _resize = Date.now();
        resizeElements(); //This resizes loads of stuff
        closeAllPopups(); //Closes any open popups
    }
});
```

Comment: A workaround would be fine. But I don't think this answer will work. I still want the onresize event to fire whenever the window is resized. This method would stop it firing again after it fires once.

Comment: No it does not. This example prevents the event from firing more than once per second. Look at the code again. Maybe you should actually try it before saying it doesn't work.